# How to insert elements into the list at arbitrary positions?

Tags: python, list

I have this

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 7, 11, 17]
```

Is there any way to add 4 characters `'-'` randomly between the other elements to achieve, for example

```
['-', 1, '-', 4, 7, '-', '-', 11, 17]
```

Comment: Use `random.randint` to generate indices at random and insert them there.

Answer (score 8):

You could simply do:

```
import random
for _ in range(4):
    a.insert(random.randint(0, len(a)), '-')
```

The loop body inserts a `'-'` at a random index between `0` and `len(a)`(inclusive). However, since inserting into a list is `O(N)`, you might be better off performance-wise constructing a new list depending on the number of inserts and the length of the list:

```
it = iter(a)
indeces = list(range(len(a) + 4))
dash_indeces = set(random.sample(indeces, 4))  # four random indeces from the available slots
a = ['-' if i in dash_indeces else next(it) for i in indeces]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has insert(index, value) list method that will do the trick.
What you want is:

```
import random

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for x in range(0, 4): # this line will ensure 4 element insertion
   l.insert(random.randrange(0, len(l)-1), '-')
```

randrange() will generate random integers from within index range of your list.
Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

You could randomly interleave the `'-'`s using iterators and `random.sample()`:

```
In [1]:
a = [1, 4, 7, 11, 17]
pop = [iter(a)]*len(a) + [iter('-'*4)]*4
[next(p) for p in random.sample(pop, k=len(pop))]

Out[1]:
['-', '-', 1, '-', 4, 7, 11, '-', 17]
```

Comment: That'd mix the order though, not just add hyphens at random positions.

Answer (score 0):

Since performance is not an issue, the following is another solution to your issue (amended per @AChampion comment):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random

_max = 4
in_list = [1, 4, 7, 11, 17]
out_list = list()

for d in in_list:
    if _max:
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            out_list.append(d)
        else:
            out_list.extend(["-", d])
            _max -= 1
    else:
        out_list.append(d)

# If not all 4 (-max) "-" have not been added, add the missing "-"s at random.
for m in range(_max):
    place = random.randrange(len(out_list)+1)
    out_list.insert(place, "-")

print(out_list)
```

Which gives:

```
$ for i in {1..15}; do python /tmp/tmp.py; done
[1, '-', 4, '-', '-', 7, 11, '-', 17]
['-', 1, 4, '-', '-', 7, 11, '-', 17]
['-', 1, 4, '-', 7, '-', 11, 17, '-']
[1, '-', 4, '-', '-', 7, '-', 11, 17]
[1, '-', 4, '-', '-', 7, 11, '-', 17]
['-', 1, 4, '-', 7, 11, '-', 17, '-']
['-', '-', 1, '-', 4, '-', 7, 11, 17]
[1, 4, '-', 7, '-', '-', '-', 11, 17]
['-', 1, 4, 7, '-', 11, '-', '-', 17]
[1, 4, '-', '-', '-', 7, '-', 11, 17]
['-', '-', 1, 4, 7, 11, '-', 17, '-']
['-', '-', 1, '-', 4, '-', 7, 11, 17]
['-', 1, '-', 4, '-', 7, 11, '-', 17]
[1, '-', 4, '-', 7, '-', 11, '-', 17]
[1, '-', '-', 4, '-', 7, 11, '-', 17]
```

Comment: This does not address the question fully, as you cannot guarantee `4` interspersed `'-'`s

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @AChampion.

Comment: Note: Your first loop is now largely unnecessary as your second loop could do all the work. And your first loop would not provide an even distribution, as it would slightly favour `'-'`s at the front.